# Can't add top margin to icon positioned over button

Tags: css

I am adding a fontawesome icon to a button like so:

```
#wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper:after{
  content: "\f0a9";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
#button{
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Download Now"/>
</div>
```

The problem is the icon doesn't look quite right.  It's a few pixels too high but I can't figure out how to adjust it.  Margin and padding move the button as well so it doesn't change anything.  Playing with vertical-align changes it but its still a few pixels out and I want a pixel perfect placement.

How do I lower/higher the icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `position: relative;` and `top: 3px;` will move it down a few pixels.

```css
#wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper:after{
  content: "\f0a9";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#button{
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="Download Now"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your wrapper next to the `input` and change it to `position: absolute` with the `height` matching the input's line-height it should do the trick:

```css
#wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper:after{
  content: "\f0a9";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
}
#button{
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Download Now" /><span id="wrapper"></span>
```

It also has the added advantage of matching the height of the input, so you don't have to use trial and error to guess the top margin.